# Easy mathematic exercise

Tags: math

Well, I have a little problem I want to solve.

We have two values.  The first can go from 100 to 75. The second can go from 50 to 40.

How can I make it so when the first value is 100, the second is 50,
and when the first value is 75, the second is 40?
(For example 87.5 should be 45 on the second value)

I am trying to find that number..  Please give me the "formula" to do so.

Comment: [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/). _Try it_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***Linear Interpolation***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)

---

0.4 · *Input* + 10 = *output*

eg:

0.4 · 87.5 + 10 = 35 -10 =  45

Comment: I would typically flag to delete this as a link-only, low-quality answer, but it seems as though the question is asking for it.

Comment: I understand this isn't a typical good-quality answer... but as you said, it does match the question. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
number2 = ( ( (number1 - 75) / 25 ) * 10 ) + 40
```